# OpenCL code get stuck on write output buffer

Tags: c++, debugging, opencl

I have this peace of code in OpenCL:

```
            std::string src = "__kernel void dot_product(__global float* weights,"
                                                        "__global float* values,"
                                                        "__global float* result,"
                                                        "__const unsigned int sz){"
                                "float dot = 0.f;"
                                "unsigned int i;"
                                "int current_idx = get_global_id(0);"
                                "unsigned int offset = current_idx * sz;"
                                "for( i = 0; i < sz; ++i )"
                                "{"
                                    "dot += weights[ offset + i ] * values[ offset + i ];"
                                "}"
                                "result[current_idx] = dot;"
                              "}";
```

Which gets stuck on result[current_idx] = dot; If I comment out this code everything works well.
I don't get why it shall get stack.

The relevant c++ code is here:

```
               using namespace cl;      
                std::array< float, CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER * CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER > in_weights;      
                std::array< float, CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER * CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER > in_values;      
                // Create a command queue and use the first device      
                const std::size_t size = in_weights.size();      
                std::vector< Device > devices =      
                 m_context.getInfo< CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES >();      
                Buffer weights(m_context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, size * sizeof(float));      
                Buffer values(m_context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, size * sizeof(float));      
                Buffer product(m_context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER * sizeof(float));      

                std::cout << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << std::endl;      

                // Set arguments to kernel      
                m_kernel.setArg(0, weights);      
                m_kernel.setArg(1, values);      
                m_kernel.setArg(2, product);      
                m_kernel.setArg(3, CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER);      
                CommandQueue queue(m_context, devices[0]);      

                try {        
                    std::vector< float > dotProducts(CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER);      
                    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER; ++i) {      
                        // Create memory buffers      
                        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER; ++j) {      
                            const std::size_t index = i * CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER + j;      
                            in_weights[index] = m_internal[i][j].weight;      
                            in_values[index] = m_internal[i][j].value;      
                        }      
                    }        

                    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(weights,      
                                             CL_TRUE,      
                                             0,      
                                             in_weights.size() * sizeof(float),      
                                             in_weights.data());      
                    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(values,      
                                             CL_TRUE,      
                                             0,      
                                             in_values.size() * sizeof(float),      
                                             in_values.data());      
                    for(std::size_t offset = 0; offset < CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER; ++offset) {      
                        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(m_kernel,      
                                                   cl::NDRange(offset),      
                                                   cl::NDRange(CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER));      
                    }        

                    std::cout << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << std::endl;      
                    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(product,      
                                            CL_TRUE,      
                                            0,      
                                            CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER * sizeof(float),      
                                            dotProducts.data());      

                    std::cout << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << std::endl;      
                    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER; ++i) {      
                        std::cout << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << std::endl;      
                        m_internal[i].calculateOutput(dotProducts.begin(),      
                                                      dotProducts.end());      
                    }        
                } catch(const cl::Error& e) {      
                    cl_int err;      
                    cl::STRING_CLASS buildlog =      
                     m_program.getBuildInfo< CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG >(devices[0], &err);      
                    std::cout << "Building error! Log: " << buildlog << std::endl;    
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which gets stuck on result[current_idx] = dot; If I comment out this
>   code everything works well. I don't get why it shall get stack.

When you comment out the line where the calculated results are being written to the output buffer then the all calculations quite likely are being removed by optimizer leaving your kernel empty.

I think here is the problem:

```
for(std::size_t offset = 0; offset < CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER; ++offset) {      
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(m_kernel, cl::NDRange(offset), cl::NDRange(CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER));      
}
```

Specifically that you loop over enqueuing many kernels that work on the same output buffer which causes each kernel fighting for access to the same one buffer where the results are being overwritten anyway.
You need to enqueue the kernel only once without offset and with `CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER` global work items:

```
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(m_kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(CONST_NEURONS_NUMBER));
```

`CONST_INPUTS_NUMBER` is already passed as a kernel argument.

Comment: This alone didn't fix my problem however adding an additional parameter to the queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel a local Range with a value 20 or 255 (something else rather than NullRange which is the default argument) solves the problem. I don't get why it does.

Comment: Ah sorry it doesn't really solve the issue. Then I get an exception.